# How to create plist in it's proper structure

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, plist

I have an array and I want to convert it into a plist.

```
XYZToDoItem *item1 = [[XYZToDoItem alloc] init];
item1.itemName = @"Buy beer";
item1.completed = YES;
[self.toDoItems addObject:item1];

XYZToDoItem *item2 = [[XYZToDoItem alloc] init];
item2.itemName = @"Buy chicken";
item2.completed = YES;
[self.toDoItems addObject:item2];
```

How can I convert it into a plist?  I try but get an error.

Comment: Please provide the code you tried. See [Property List Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't.

Property lists can't contain custom objects like your XYZToDoItem. They can only contain a fairly small list of object types (NSString, NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects).

If you want to serialize an array that contains custom objects like your XYZToDoItem, you should look at making your object conform to NSCoding. You could then convert the array to NSData using the NSKeyedArchiver method archivedDataWithRootObject, or write it directly to disk using 
archiveRootObject:toFile:

Comment: Hi Duncan, I am trying to create plist manually with the mutable array items contains string 'itemName' and boolean value .

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "create plist manually with the mutable array items...". Are you trying to write a file yourself that is a well-formed plist file? That would be quite a bit of work.

Comment: yes . correct . i just try to write a plist file myself .

Comment: Ok, that's silly. It's a lot of needless work, and it relies on the private implementation details of plists, which is never a good idea.

Comment: Better to build an array of the "stuff" that you want in the plist, and then save that using NSArray's writeToFile:atomically: method.

Comment: i try to write. but it failed

Comment: See my answer. you can only write property list objects into a property list.